# generate b2Body for a letter

Tags: javascript, box2d

I want to code a little Game, dealing with fonts and letters. I want to make them move arround in 2d space and i am using box2dweb as physics engine, what is actually doing a very great job. At the moment all I am struggling with, is the problem of building the b2Body for a Letter. Box2d can only handle primitive, convex shapes and to build an more complex hitbox I have to combine some of them. In the image I tried to figure out what i would like to reach, an algorithm, that takes an svg-path of a letter and generates a series of b2shapes which represent the hitbox.

[image: capital letter A in Black, a series of b2Shapes in blue, with green stroke]

All in all i have no Idea where i could find some Information about this, if there is a library that is capable of doing this. Even if this Library is not available in Javascript, i could do the job on Server.
I know that there is paper.js and raphalel, some clever vector libraries, but i have not found any hint how to solve this yet.
I would be happy for any kind of help, links to ressources, or the correct name of the problem in mathematical sense.

Greetings and thanks in advance...
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to leave the result of investigation here, maybe someone will help it. The initial idea is based on »ear cutting«, »ear culling«, or »ear cropping«. A demo [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Ian/applet1.html) will describe this. But the algorithm, which produces less, but box2d suitable polygons is shown in a demo [here](http://www.splashdust.net/2009/10/box2d-mouse-drawing-now-with-ear-clipping/). The idea is to merge as much triangles as possible, as long as they are convex and this case, do not have more than eight edges. A triangle is suitable to be added to a polygon, if one can find two points in the triangle and two adjective points in the polygon, with the same x and y coordinates.